# Type on a path - non compound, non masking paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text-on-path

I'm trying to figure out how to use the type on a path tool in Illustrator.
I used the curvature tool to draw a wavy line, which I now want to type on.
I keep getting a message that I cannot make any sense of. It reads:

> YOU MUST CLICK ON A NON-COMPOUND, NON-MASKING PATH TO CREATE TEXT
> INSIDE A PATH.

I have seen [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16239/adobe-illustrator-error-creating-text-constrained-by-shape-area-type-tool?newreg=3e5fd902b9ca4b53865a1c1640063e6c), which describes the same problem, but I tried the answers suggested and they're not working. I wonder if something has changed in illustrator since this question was last answered?

Comment: Do you want type **on a path** or type **inside a shape**? The question you linked to refers to *inside a shape*.

Comment: In general, you use the Type on a path **tool** and merely click directly on a path.

Answer (score 1):

That message tells that your path isn't a simple path. Type on Path tool doesn't accept anything else. An example:

[image]

A circle isn't accepted. But closer inspection reveals that my circle is a compound path:

[image]

It's made of a circular path by applying Outline Stroke. Expanding a closed path and some Pathfinder panel operations make also compound paths. They are the way to have holes in Illustrator.

Try Object > Compound Path > Release.

Make a copy because if your path happens to have several components you may want to delete the unwanted ones. What's left vanishes when it's used as a path of text.

A path which is clipping mask for another path also cannot be a path of a text. You get the same error message if you try to edit a clipping mask and apply Type on Path.

A path which is made partially invisible with a clipping mask can well be a path of text. Only that part of the text stays visible which fits below the clipping mask.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the path being compound or masking, if it is a sub-layer you will not be able to type text onto it. If this is the case copy the sub-layer into a new layer.